# Родительский div не меняет высоту

Tags: вёрстка, html

Проблема в верстке, а именно с родительским div, который не принимает высоту содержимого. Почитал решения в интернете, но для списка ничего не подошло.

HTML:

```
                <!-- NOMENCLATURA !-->
                <div id="goods_list">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="g_img"></div>
                            <p class="g_name">
                                АК47
                            </p>
                            <p class="g_desc">
                                Наиболее смертельна стрельба короткими и точными очередями. Покрашен вручную на спортивный мотив.
                            </p>
                            <div class="buy_button">
                                <p id="text">
                                    2370р. - подробнее
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="border"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="g_img"></div>
                            <p class="g_name">
                                АК47
                            </p>
                            <p class="g_desc">
                                Наиболее смертельна стрельба короткими и точными очередями. Покрашен вручную на спортивный мотив.
                            </p>
                            <div class="buy_button">
                                <p id="text">
                                    2370р. - подробнее
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="border"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="g_img"></div>
                            <p class="g_name">
                                АК47
                            </p>
                            <p class="g_desc">
                                Наиболее смертельна стрельба короткими и точными очередями. Покрашен вручную на спортивный мотив.
                            </p>
                            <div class="buy_button">
                                <p id="text">
                                    2370р. - подробнее
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="border"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="g_img"></div>
                            <p class="g_name">
                                АК47
                            </p>
                            <p class="g_desc">
                                Наиболее смертельна стрельба короткими и точными очередями. Покрашен вручную на спортивный мотив.
                            </p>
                            <div class="buy_button">
                                <p id="text">
                                    2370р. - подробнее
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="border"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="g_img"></div>
                            <p class="g_name">
                                АК47 
                            </p>
                            <p class="g_desc">
                                Наиболее смертельна стрельба короткими и точными очередями. Покрашен вручную на спортивный мотив.
                            </p>
                            <div class="buy_button">
                                <p id="text">
                                    2370р. - подробнее
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="border"></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <!-- / NOMENCLATURA !-->
```

CSS:

```
/* NOMENCLATURA START. */
#goods_list {
width: 788px;
margin: 26px 0 0 -34px;
border-left: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
}

#goods_list ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#goods_list li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
width: 197px;
height: 321px;
background: #fff;
border-top: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
border-right: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#goods_list li .border {
width: 100%;
height: 6px;
background: #29c3f4;

}

#goods_list .g_img {
background: url(../images/g_1.png) no-repeat;
margin: 0;
width: 195px;
height: 95px;
}
.g_name {
color: #ff6631;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 18px;
}
.g_desc {
color: #333;
font-style: italic;
text-align: center;
height: 92.75px;
}
#goods_list .buy_button {
color: #31a3ff;
width: 153px;
height: 35px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
border-radius: 45px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
#goods_list .buy_button #text {
margin-top: 9px;
text-align: center;
}

/* NOMENCLATURA END. */
```

Comment: у вас внутренние дивы с float, они не включаются в подсчет размера. добавьте в конце `<div style="clear:both"></div>`. Должно заработать

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить clearfix.

```css
#goods_list:before,
#goods_list:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
}

#goods_list:after {
  clear:both;
}

#goods_list {
  zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте у дочерних элементов поставить в стиль свойство box-sizing: border-box

Answer (score 0):

добавь float:left; родительскому блоку

```
#goods_list {
  width: 788px;
  margin: 26px 0 0 -34px;
  border-left: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: разве мой ответ не решает проблему? я ведь проверил, блок #goods_list растянулся по высоте. Или я не правильно понял вопрос?